# Javascript Prototypes that represent HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been thinking about making Javascript Prototypes that represent HTML elements.
For example a form prototype with build in ajax requests and form element prototypes. Or a list with list item prototypes.

I think that the biggest benefit of this approach is that it reduces repetitive code.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8mEUZ/) of what I have in mind.

```
var LightParticle = function() {
    this.setWidth(10);
    this.setHeight(10);
    this.setTop(0);
    this.setLeft(0);
    this.setPosition("absolute");
    this.setBackground("white");
    this.setClassName("LightParticle");
};

LightParticle.prototype = {
    setWidth : function(width) {
        this.width = width; 
    },
    getWidth : function() {
        return this.width;
    },
    setHeight : function(height) {
        this.height = height;   
    },
    getHeight : function() {
        return this.height;
    },
    setTop : function(top) {
        this.top = top; 
    },
    getTop : function() {
        return this.top;
    },
    setLeft : function(left) {
        this.left = left;   
    },
    getLeft : function() {
        return this.left;
    },
    setBackground : function(background) {
        this.background = background;   
    },
    getBackground : function() {
        return this.background;
    },
    setClassName : function(className) {
        this.className = className; 
    },
    getClassName : function() {
        return this.className;
    },
    setElement : function(element) {
        this.element = element;
    },
    getElement : function(element) {
        return this.element;
    },
    setPosition : function(position) {
        this.position = position;
    },
    getPosition : function(position) {
        return this.position;
    },
    setSize : function(size) {
        this.setWidth(size);
        this.setHeight(size);
    },
    getStyle : function() {
        return {
            position: this.getPosition(),
            width : this.getWidth(),
            height : this.getHeight(),
            top : this.getTop(),
            left: this.getLeft(),
            background: this.getBackground()
        }       
    },
    getView : function() {
        var element = $("<div></div>");
        element
        .addClass(this.getClassName())
        .css(this.getStyle());
        this.setElement(element);
        return element; 
    },
    pulsate : function (speed) {
        var height = this.getHeight();
        var width = this.getWidth();
        var top = this.getTop();
        var left = this.getLeft();
        if(this.getElement().height() == height) {
            height = height * 4;
            width = width * 4;
            top = top - (height/2);
            left = left - (width/2);
        }
        $(this.getElement()).animate({
            "height":height, 
            "width": width,
            "top": top,
            "left":left
        }, speed);
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            that.pulsate(speed);
        }, speed);  
    }
}

function addRandomParticle() {
    try {
        var particle = new LightParticle();
        var seed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 70) + 1;
        particle.setBackground("#" + Math.floor((Math.abs(Math.sin(seed) * 16777215)) % 16777215).toString(16));
        particle.setSize(Math.floor(Math.random() * 70) + 10);
        particle.setTop(Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).height()));
        particle.setLeft(Math.floor(Math.random() * $(window).width()));
        $('#canvas').append(particle.getView());
        particle.pulsate(Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000) + 500);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    try {
        for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            addRandomParticle();    
        }
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
});
```

So far I'm not satisfied with the getters and setters since they have no datatype validation.

Does anyone have any idea how I can improve this? Or does someone know a completely better approach to reduce javascript code/events?

Comment: How does this "reduce repetitive code to a minimum" ?

Comment: Not really related to your question, but why so many try/catch? It's javascript, not java. Exceptions are really exceptional.

Comment: The setters and getters also look more like the verbosity of java than like a dry framework.

Comment: Since you're using jQuery already, how about replacing that entire class with `var particle = $("<div></div>").addClass("LightParticle").css({position: "absolute", width: "10px", height: "10px", background: "white"});` - from there, animate it however you like. E.g. using jquery's `animate()`...

Comment: @dystroy I agree on that, however I really wanjt to validate the incoming datatypes.

Comment: @Flambino Constructing the particle isn't the problem. The repetitive events are.

Comment: @Sem Oh, I understand that, but 70% of your code right now is constructing the particle. If you want to avoid repetition, then don't duplicate jQuery's functionality. Besides, a jQuery obj already "represents an HTML element" (or several, of course). Build on top of that, wrap things in functions, etc.. For a more direct HTML-to-obj connection, look at Prototype JS, which extends prototypes (which is nasty, although the resulting syntax is neat, IMHO)

Comment: @Flambino Alright, i'll make a better example soon.

Comment: But...light particles have no width and height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As dystroy mentioned, the setters and getters are really not JavaScript style, neither are the many `try/catch` statements in your functions.

However, if you insist on having all these getters and setters, you should create a utility function that generates a getter/setter  for you. Since you have default values for most properties in your `LightParticle` I was thinking something along the lines of this :

```
function addGetterSetter( o , property , defaultValue ){
  var postFix = property[0].toUpperCase() + property.slice(1),
      getter  = 'get' + postFix,
      setter  = 'set' + postFix;
  o[getter] = function(){
    return this[property] || defaultValue;
  }
  o[setter] = function( value ){
    this[property] = value;
    return this;
  }  
}
```

And then you would

```
var LightParticle = function() {},
    prototype = LightParticle.prototype;

addGetterSetter( prototype , width   , 10 );
addGetterSetter( prototype , height  , 10 );
addGetterSetter( prototype , top     , 0 );
addGetterSetter( prototype , left    , 0 );
addGetterSetter( prototype , position, 'absolute' );
addGetterSetter( prototype , background, 'white' );
addGetterSetter( prototype , className , 'LightParticle' );
```